# triac optocoupler with dual output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, opto-isolator, triac

I'm having trouble finding a tric coupled photo with two independent outputs. Diode input can be the same, it is not necessary if 2 separate diodes. Someone could indicate a specific model, website or name of the component.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with series connecting the LEDs in the device pictured in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Dual isolated high speed optos [exist](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/mv1rwblv8w/FAIR-S-A0002366073-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw).

Dual LED to one output are used for linear feedback.

I’ve never seen 1 LED to dual outputs, so cascade the LED’s in series.

Opto Triacs with ZCS come in [singles](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/qt-brightek-qtb/QTT0213ST1/8445568?s=N4IgjCBcoCwdIDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRDgFYBOMAdhAMqoCYAGEAXQIAcAXKEAGVeAJwCWAOwDmIAL4EwVABxUooZJHTZ8RUiHZcQfAcPHS5BALQw1SVJlwFikMgDYAzGGbvOs%2BSGY9AHk%2BQgACUTE0ZA5ZIA).